# jquery.matchHeight.js not working in Fire Fox

Tags: jquery, firefox

I am trying to use matchHeight.js in my site. It seems to work great in Webkit but is not taking in Firefox. You can see the grid is breaking in multiple places in Firefox especially when the products are 3 across.

http://173.254.28.162/~newgrowt/new_growth/shop/

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine in Firefox 37 and 38.0a2.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I am running 37 and am having broken grids. You didnt see any empty product spaces in the grids when you scrolled down?

Comment: I just changed to the conformity.js plugin from codekipple and it seems to have done the trick. So far so good. Thanks again for looking at this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Internal Server error now. Fixed, sort of :-)

@Sean Burles, do you have this visible somewhere else?